# Hosts file - Error 404

Tags: iis-7, http-status-code-404, hosts

I am trying to run test and production sites in ASP.NET IIS config. I have following entries in my Hosts file:

```
172.16.5.178    testsite       ### test site
172.16.170.41   www.mysite.com  ### LIVE WEBSITE
```

I have two problems here: I can not navigate to my test site using IP Address or using "testsite" in browser. I tried using all combinations: `http://testsite, http://mysite:8080, http://mysite:80, 172.16.5.178, 172.16.5.178:80` and so on. But none of them works for me.

If I however use following entry, it works correctly:

```
 172.16.5.178   www.mysite.com  ### test site
```

Note that I used Test Server IP Address and actual Name from Live Site, and it worked.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening? I thought writing in Hosts file will navigate to respective IP Address no matter what I use as name. And indeed it goes to that IP address but shows "Not Found" and "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found." error.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing your hosts file will basically send your browser to the designated IP address for that host/url. The destination IP address has to have something on the other end that is expecting that, if that makes sense.

If you set up a site in IIS on 172.16.5.178 called `testsite`, with a binding of `testsite`, then it would work fine, as it then knows what to do with that request. Then going to `http://testsite` will work. I'm assuming that's the part you are missing!

I've personally got plenty of development sites in my hosts file pointing to an IIS installation on a network server. You just need to make sure the destination server can work out what to do with `testsite`.